# Add child object in Core Data relationship - Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, one-to-many

I have two Entitys one called Cupboard one Drawer with a one to many Relationship Cupboard<->>Drawer. For Cupboards I use a collectionView and I created a segue to a tableView(Drawer). But I don't know how I add new Drawers to Cupboard when I'm in the DrawerViewController

I save my Cupboard like this:

```
func saveCupboard(name: String, type: String){
    let cupboard = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Cupboard", into: managedContext) as! Cupboard

    cupboard.name = name
    cupboard.type = type

    saveContext()

}

lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

    var context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.storeCoordinator

    return context
}()

func saveContext() {
    if managedContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

My segue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDrawer" {
        let dst = segue.destination as! DrawerViewController

        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else{
            return
        }
        dst.cupboard = ??
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me there.
Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

```
 lazy var fetchedResultsCtrl: NSFetchedResultsController<Cupboard> = {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Cupboard> = Cupboard.fetchRequest()

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let fetchedCtrl = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: appDelegate.coreDataResource.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    fetchedCtrl.delegate = self

    return fetchedCtrl
}()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDrawer" {
        let dst = segue.destination as! DrawerViewController

        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else{
            return
        }
        dst.cupboard = cupboards[indexPath.row] as! Cupboard //Pass the cupboard to DrawerViewController.
    }
}
```

You can pass the cupboard to DrawerViewController like above. Then at the time of  adding new drawer in DrawerViewController, you have to just set

```
let newDrawer = Drawer(context:moc) 
newDrawer.cupboard = cupboard
```

As there is one to many relationships between cupboard and drawer.

Comment: what do you mean with `(context:moc)`? Sry if that is Basic Stuff

Comment: If you want to insert new drawer in a cupboard from DrawerViewController, you have to create or access managedObjectContext(moc).

Comment: Oke Thank u so much! I will give it a try tomorrow and report back then

Comment: Soo i thought ill try it out now and `dst.cupboard = cupboards[indexPath.row] as! Cupboard` tells me `Use of unresolved identifier 'cupboards'`.  I call cupboard in my CollectionView like that `let cupboard = fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath) `

Comment: yeah it will show, actually here "cupboards" means, your array that is acting as data source (Collection or array of Cupboard) for the CollectionView.

Comment: This should be the `fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath)` or not? cause i know how this normally works with the array but I don't really have one in my CollectionView

Comment: yes, this should be like this fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159790/discussion-between-sane-and-boudhayan).

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how I add new Drawers to Cupboard when I'm in the DrawerViewController

Make sure that you have enabled class generation for your managed object model. Then you have classes Drawer and Cupboard. So you would say:

```
let drawer = Drawer(context:context)
drawer.cupboard = // ... the cupboard we already saved
```

Comment: Thanks and do you know how I use the segue right? How do I get the `indexPath.row` there, cause normally I have a list like `var listen = [Liste]()` but not this time. I updated my Question that u see how I fetch my Data. I'm really new to swift/programming/coreData so... sry for that Question if it sounds dump for you

Comment: I mean in the CollectionView

Comment: Hmm yeah.. I thought maybe you can help me there also. But thank you for your time